# Calling find more than once on the same folder tree

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, find

I'm running a find command multiple times on the same group of files. The results of my find commands are usually disjoint sets, AKA I'm running find -mmin +35; find -mmin -25, and doing different things to the results.

It seems sort of silly to search through the entire file system multiple times when one search would do. Is there a way to put multiple "search parameters" into a single find command and pipe the ouput to a different place depending on which parameter it satisfies?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . -mmin +35 -or -mmin -25
```

find supports several logical operators (-and, -or, -not).  See the OPERATORS section of the man pages for more details.

====================
EDIT: In response to the question about processing the two matches differently, I do not know of a way to do this directly with find.  Personally what I would do is to process the output in a for loop like this (note this is pesudo-code):

```
for f in `find . [condition 1] -or [condition 2]` ;do
    if [ f meets condition1 ]; then
        doSomething
    elif [ f meets condition2 ]; then
        doSomethingElse
    fi
done
```

I'm sure there are many bash gurus out there who could do this cleaner and more efficiently.

Comment: But is there a way to pipe the results of -mmin +35 to one command (rm for example) and the results of -mmin -25 to another command (rsync for example)?

Comment: OK, I see what you are asking.  My initial thought is "no", because the output is in the same stream.  If however you wanted to put this in a loop, that examines each match, that might work.  I'll edit my answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tee` to copy the output to two different subshells and process it differently.

```
find . -mmin +35 -or -mmin -25 | tee \
    >(while read f; do if [ $f meets condition1 ]; then; doSomething; done) \
    >(while read f; do if [ $f meets condition2 ]; then; doSomethingElse; done) \
    >/dev/null
```

That is the first solution that came to my mind after reading EJK's answer.

Edit: This is untested. A working example showing the principle is the following:

```
echo -e "abc\ndef\nauv\nafg\ndtt" | tee >(grep -P '^a' > a.txt) >(grep -P '^d' > d.txt) >/dev/null
```